# Solved -- Cento OS 6 update error RHEL6 not found

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

This is for anyone who's having issues updating Cento OS 6.

When you try to run `yum -y update` on Cento OS 6, you get an error of VMWare package not found

> http://packages.vmware.com/tools/releases/latest/rhel6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml

You need to update the file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/vmware-tools.repo` with the new path

> https://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/rhel6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml

And That's it.